# how to get coreprofilesessiontap result?

Tags: python, ios, go, interface, instruments

when i use electricbubble/gidevice
https://github.com/electricbubble/gidevice/blob/main/pkg/libimobiledevice/keyedarchiver.go
call

```
com.apple.instruments.server.services.coreprofilesessiontap
```

interface by
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3KCZ.png)
after start it's return like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uolnC.png)
but when i use python in py-ios-device it return succssful data like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtQvd.png)
has anyone met the same thing?
how can i do to get the right data

has anyone met the same thing?
how can i do to get the right data

code like this

```
    option := map[string]interface{}{
    "rp": 10,
    "tc": []map[string]interface{}{
        {
            "kdf2": []int64{630784000, 833617920, 830472456},
            "tk":   3,
            "uuid": strings.ToUpper(uuid.New().String()),
        }},
    "ur": 1000,
}
if _, err := c.i.call(instrumentsServiceCoreprofilesessiontap, "setConfig:", option); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
    return nil, err
}
if _, err := c.i.call(instrumentsServiceCoreprofilesessiontap, "start"); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of code: post code as text.

Comment: ok, i have posted the code as text